# Subquery with multiple conditions referencing different tables?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm going through sqlzoo.net's tutorials and I'm trying to wrap my head around subqueries and `JOIN`. While doing this, I try to write the same code once with `JOIN` and once with subqueries. Now I wonder if I can use subqueries when there are multiple conditions.

Currently I'm working on question 8 and 9 [of this problem set](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations); at the top of the site I linked you can see the tables being used. I managed to get #8 ("List the films in which 'Harrison Ford' has appeared") right.

With `JOIN`:

```
SELECT m.title
FROM movie m
JOIN casting c ON c.movieid = m.id
JOIN actor a ON a.id = c.actorid
WHERE a.name = 'Harrison Ford'
```

With subqueries:

```
SELECT title 
FROM movie
WHERE id IN (SELECT movieid FROM casting 
WHERE actorid IN (SELECT id FROM actor WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford'))
```

Question 9 is the same, but adds another condition: Not only should the films star Harrison Ford, but he also must not be lead actor. The actors' names are stored in the table "actor", the lead/not lead info is in the table "casting"

So with `JOIN` I simply add another condition via `AND`:

```
SELECT title
FROM movie m
JOIN casting c ON c.movieid = m.id 
JOIN actor a ON a.id = c.actorid 
WHERE a.name = 'Harrison Ford' and c.ord != 1
```

How would I do this with subqueries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it to the subquery:

```
SELECT title 
FROM movie
WHERE id IN (SELECT movieid FROM casting c
WHERE actorid IN (SELECT id FROM actor WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford') And c.ord != 1)
```

Comment: Well, that was easy...

Thank you!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!